# Unir dos inputs a un var en javascript

Tags: javascript, php

quisiera unir dos datos que se ingresan en dos inputs como lo muestro en el siguiente codigo, es la base de un generador de QR basado en PHP y JS

Necesito que el datosqr se sume a datosqr2 y que al llamar la variable muestre algo asi

Ejemplo: datosqr/datosqr2

```js
var qrdata = document.getElementById("datosqr", "datosqr2") ;
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"));
```

```html
<form method="post">
                <label for="datosqr">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="datosqr" id="datosqr" placeholder="Ingresa Los Datos" style="width: 60%"/>
                <br>
                <label for="datosqr2">RUT</label>
                <input type="text" name="datosqr2" id="datosqr2" placeholder="Ingresa Los Datos" style="width: 60%"/>
              </form>
```

Comment: Tienes que alcanzar los elementos por su id de forma individual (cada id es único) y luego adicionar los contenidos. Tampoco queda claro cuál es el evento encargado de lanzar el código, ni queda claro qué debe pasar si uno de los input cambia de valor.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Mírate [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y ganar tu primera medalla!  En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿has probado con recoger cada dato de forma individual y luego haces la operacion o concatenación que deseas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo como te mencionan en los comentarios deberías capturar sus valores individualmente. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, utilizando Jquery para capturar el evento de envio.

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="datosqr">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="datosqr" id="datosqr" placeholder="Ingresa Los Datos" style="width: 60%"/>
        <br>
        <label for="datosqr2">RUT</label>
        <input type="text" name="datosqr2" id="datosqr2" placeholder="Ingresa Los Datos" style="width: 60%"/>
        <input type="submit" name="" id="btnSubmit">
    </form>
    <hr/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnSubmit").click( ()=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            var qrdata1 = document.getElementById("datosqr").value;
            var qrdata2 = document.getElementById("datosqr2").value;
            var QrCode = qrdata2 + qrdata1;
            console.log(QrCode)
            //var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrdata"));
        })
       
    </script>
</body>
```